# SSL for sub domain on shared hosting

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, subdomain, cpanel

I want to generate and install SSL certificate for a sub-domain.
The sub-domain is used with a different server (A record points to the IP) and it's where I want to add the certificate.

It's a shared hosting, with CPANEL, so it's easy to generate and install certificates, but I'm not sure how I should generate and install SSL with this setup, without going into the domain settings... if it's possible, any suggestions?

If not, please explain what should be done in such case..

Answer (score 0):

This is Class 2 certificate as provided by letsencrypt? Only 2 requirements need be met:

- DNS entry for specific address: `sub.domain.xxx`
- ... which points to a web server where you have access to the index directory.

tools like `getssl` https://github.com/srvrco/getssl then can obtain the certificate by putting down a key in s sub directory for validation.

Answer (score 0):

If your cPanel installation is up to date you could request that cPanels AutoSSL be enabled. This would then automatically get a signed certificate approved by comodo and install it on any domains or sub domains that have it enabled on the server via the interface.